# How to get pass this part of the city guide skill ? amazon sdk python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I been working on this Alexa skills and I'm almost done, but I'm stuck on this part:

> Finish configuring your function. Click on your function's name
>   (you'll find it in the middle) and scroll to the bottom of the page,
>   you'll see a Cloud9 code editor.
>
> We have provided the code for this skill here. To properly upload this
>   code to Lambda, you'll need to perform the following:
>
> This skill uses the ASK SDK for Python for development. The skill code
>   is provided in the lambda_function.py, and the dependencies are
>   mentioned in requirements.txt. Download the contents of the lambda/py
>   folder.
>
> On your system, navigate to the lambda folder and install the
>   dependencies in a new folder called “skill_env” using the following
>   command:
>
> `pip install -r py/requirements.txt -t skill_env`
>
> Copy the contents of
>   the lambda/py folder into the skill_env folder.
>
> `cp -r py/* skill_env/`
>
> Zip the contents of the skill_env folder.
>
> Remember to zip the contents of the folder and NOT the folder itself.
>
> `pip install -r py/requirements.txt -t skill_env`    <--- this part doesn't not work for me in cmd

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please add the errors that you are getting to your question?

Comment: Thank for the responds , I'm just stuck at this point once i imstall the sdk im lost

Comment: In your question your said the last part "doesn't not work for me." How do you know it's not working? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: No errors just stuck,"Copy the contents of the lambda/py folder into the skill_env folder."